# PHP file upload - out of memory

Tags: php, apache, amazon-ec2

I have a Symfony application using Sonata admin and Sonata media my client uses to upload mp4 videos. The problem is these files are getting bigger and bigger (> 1go) and I now have trouble with "out of memory" apache errors.

The website is hosted on an AWS EC2 ubuntu instance (PHP, Apache2). 
I set the `php.ini` parameters like this:

```
upload_max_filesize = 1G
post_max_size = 2G
memory_limit = -1
```

I did this for cli and apache2 under /etc/php/7.0/. I tried various combinations and higher values. Always restart apache afterwards. I even tried rebooting the instance. I can't get to upload more than 350mo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found a solution. Here's how I did it.

First of all, i stopped my EC2 instance, detached the volume and made a snapshot of it.

From the snapshot, I created a bigger volume (30Go for now). I reattached it to my EC2 instance, which I rebooted.

I logged in through SSH and installed a swapspace (3Go). Tweaked it a little following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04).

I cleant the cache, restarted my EC2 instance one last time and... well I just uploaded 1Go in 20 minutes.

One issue though : stopping and starting my EC2 instance I lost my IP and had to change my DNS zone. It's gonna take a few hours for the website to be back...

Hope this will be helpful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure of the right syntax  ? I think it's in bytes like

1000 bytes = 1Mo so just write the number without "G","Mb",etc..
But im not sure try it and return response :)

Comment: I changed 1G for 1000M and rebooted the instance. Doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your `.htaccess` file in the project root directory or make sure that in the Symfony project files, the size is not limited with the PHP functions, which will overwrite the `php.ini` attributes.

Comment: Here comes my .htaccess file :

`# Expires is set to a point we won't reach,
# Cache control will trigger first, 10 days after access
# 10 Days = 60s x 60m x 24hrs x 10days =  864,000
<FilesMatch "\.(webm|ogg|mp4)$">
Header set Expires "Mon, 27 Mar 2038 13:33:37 GMT"
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=864000"
</FilesMatch>
AddType video/webm .webm`

Comment: it seems ok. check the configurations php files in your project

Comment: As far as I know there is nothing like that in my config.yml.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your php.ini file upload_max_filesize = 100000

Because if you write 1G it will not count 1 GB it sounts in byte so you will have to declare 1048576 for uploading limit of 1 GB